# Url isn't well formed in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here is the LOC that I tried to present an external link however, it is prefixed with the local route.

```
<a href="@Url.Content(@Model.ExternalWebsite)">
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the documentation on `Url.Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_Content_):

> Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

So this method is *explicitly* to interpret a path as a relative path to the application and convert it into an absolute application URL.

If `Model.ExternalWebsite` is an absolute address, just use that one directly:

```
<a href="@Model.ExternalWebsite">…</a>
```

Comment: thank you for the message. In fact, I tried the direct one earlier and found that, it also results in the same incorrect url - https://localhost:xxx/Test/www.yahoo.com

Comment: Check the HTML output. It’s likely just generating `<a href="www.yahoo.com"` which is not a valid absolute URL. URLs start with the protocol (http or https).